# How to convert array to image colour channel in python?

Tags: python, image, numpy, scikit-learn, python-imaging-library

I need to split colour channel of the image (specifically "Cb") in 8x8 blocks in order to modify DCT coefficients and reassemble them back later.

I'm trying to do it using [image.extract_patches_2d()](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.image.extract_patches_2d.html)

However I can't seem to reassemble the channel

```
from PIL import Image
from sklearn.feature_extraction import image
import numpy as np

pic = Image.open('lama.png')
pic_size = pic.size
ycbcr = pic.convert('YCbCr')
(y, cb, cr) = ycbcr.split()


acb = np.asarray(cb)
patches = image.extract_patches_2d(acb, (8, 8))
acb2 = image.reconstruct_from_patches_2d(patches, (500,500))
cb_n = Image.fromarray(acb2, 'L')
```

Even without any changes to the patches reassembled array does not correspond to the original channel:

cb saved as image:

[image]

Cb restored from patches (cb_n in code):

[image]

So is there something wrong with the code? Or is it impossible to restore colour channel from pathces (blocks) using [image.reconstruct_from_patches_2d](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.image.reconstruct_from_patches_2d.html#sklearn.feature_extraction.image.reconstruct_from_patches_2d)?

And if so, is there a better way to do what I need?

Thanks for reading, appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before calling `Image.fromarray()` on `acb2`, make sure to change the dtype to int as it was in the beginning. The `image.reconstruct_from_patches_2d` changes your picture values to float64, whereas the original values in `cb` are `uint8`. This is the only source of error I am getting. Other than that your code is working as expected.

Change your code from:

```
acb2 = image.reconstruct_from_patches_2d(patches, (500,500))
cb_n = Image.fromarray(acb2, 'L')
```

to:

```
acb2 = image.reconstruct_from_patches_2d(patches, (500,500))
#ADD THIS LINE
acb2 = acb2.astype(np.uint8)
cb_n = Image.fromarray(acb2, 'L')
```

**NOTE:** (Unrelated to above)

Also make sure you are using correct dimensions in `reconstruct_from_patches_2d` for the image size. As you have specified `(500,500)`, I am assuming that the width is same as height (500). But in images where height and width are different, `Image module` will be **column-major** whereas numpy (and python arrays by default) are **row-major**.
So,

```
pic_size = pic.size
```

will report output `(Width, Height)`, But when using in `reconstruct_from_patches_2d`, use `(Height, Width)`.