# How to Use Sci-kit Learn reconstruct_from_patches_2d

Tags: python, image, image-processing, scikit-learn, image-segmentation

I'm working on an imaging project that needs to read images, split them into overlapping patches, run some operation on the patches, and then recombine them into a single image. For this task, I decided to the sci-kit learn methods extract_patches_2d, and reconstruct_from_patches_2d.

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.image.extract_patches_2d.html
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.image.reconstruct_from_patches_2d.html

```python
import numpy as np
import cv2
from sklearn.feature_extraction import image as extraction

img = cv2.imread("cat_small.jpg", cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
grid_size = 500
images = extraction.extract_patches_2d(img, (grid_size, grid_size), max_patches=100)
image = extraction.reconstruct_from_patches_2d(images, img.shape)
cv2.imwrite("stack_overflow_test.jpg", image)
```

I can tell the extraction works correctly, since each of the patches can be saved as an individual image. The reconstruction does not work.

The image:
[image: Picture of a cat]

becomes:
[image: Black image with white at the top]

Which looks entirely black when viewed on a white background, but does have some white pixels toward the top left (can be seen when opened in a separate tab). This same problem happens in grayscale.

I have tried adding astype(np.uint8) as explained in 
[How to convert array to image colour channel in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42920188/how-to-convert-array-to-image-colour-channel-in-python)
to no avail. How is this method used properly?

Comment: I am having this same issue.  I noticed that it works if in `extraction.extract_patches_2d` you don't specify the max patches parameter.

Comment: Looking at the source code, `reconstruct_from_patches_2d` assumes a stride of 1, which is not the case if  `max_patches` is specified.

Comment: Hi Austin Lackey, I am having the same issue, when I change the stride from 1 to another value., did you find any solution for that?